# Java regex backreference for two digits

Tags: java, regex

I am working with a regex and I want to use it on the `replaceAll` method of the String class in Java.

My regex works fine and `groupCount()` returns 11. So, when I try to replace my text using backreference pointing to the eleventh group, I am getting the first group with a "1" attached to it, instead of the group eleven.

```
String regex = "(>[^<]*?)((\+?\d{1,4}[ \t\f\-\.](\d[ \t\f\-\.])?)?(\(\d{1,4}([\s-]\d{1,4})?\)[\.\- \t\f])?((\d{2,6}[\.\- \t\f])+\d{2,6})|(\d{6,16})([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?)([^<]*<)";
String text = "<span style=\"font-size:11.0pt\">675-441-3144;;;78888464#<o:p></o:p></span>":
String replacement = text.replaceAll(regex, $1<a href="tel:$2">$2</a>$11");
```

I am expecting to get the following result:

```
<span style=\"font-size:11.0pt\"><a href=\"tel:675-441-3144;;;78888464#\">675-441-3144;;;78888464#</a><o:p></o:p></span>
```

But the $11 backreference is not returning the 11th group, it is returning the first group with a 1 attached to it, and instead I am getting the following result:

```
<span style="font-size:11.0pt"><a href="tel:675-441-3144">675-441-3144</a>>1o:p></o:p></span>
```

Can someone please tell me how to access the eleventh group of my pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use an XML/HTML parser here?

Comment: Works fine for me: `"za".replaceAll("(z)()()()()()()()()()(a)", "$1 $11")` outputs `z a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

The way you access the eleventh group of a match in the replacement is with `$11`.

### Explanation:

As the [corresponding Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-)* states:

> The replacement string may contain references to subsequences captured
>   during the previous match: Each occurrence of `${name}` or `$g` will be
>   replaced by the result of evaluating the corresponding [group(name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-java.lang.String-) or
>   [group(g)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) respectively. For `$g`, the first number after the `$` is always
>   treated as part of the group reference. Subsequent numbers are
>   incorporated into `g` if they would form a legal group reference.

So generally speaking, as long as have at least eleven groups, then `"$11"` will evaluate to `group(11)`.  However, if you do not have at least eleven groups, then `"$11"` will evaluate to `group(1) + "1"`.

* *This quote is from `Matcher#appendReplacement(StringBuffer,String)`, which is where the chain of relevant citations from `String#replaceAll(String,String)` leads to.*

---

## Actual Answer

Your regex does not do what you think it does.

### Part 1

#### The Problem

Let's divide your regex into its three top-level groups.  These are groups 1, 2, and 11, respectively.

- Group 1:
  `(>[^<]*?)`
- Group 2:
  `((\+?\d{1,4}[ \t\f\-\.](\d[ \t\f\-\.])?)?(\(\d{1,4}([\s-]\d{1,4})?\)[\.\- \t\f])?((\d{2,6}[\.\- \t\f])+\d{2,6})|(\d{6,16})([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?)`
- Group 11:
  `([^<]*<)`

Group 2 is the main body of your regex, and it consists of a top-level alternation over two options.  These two options consist of groups 3-8 and 9-10, respectively.

- First option:
  `((\+?\d{1,4}[ \t\f\-\.](\d[ \t\f\-\.])?)?(\(\d{1,4}([\s-]\d{1,4})?\)[\.\- \t\f])?((\d{2,6}[\.\- \t\f])+\d{2,6})`
- Second option:
  `(\d{6,16})([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?)`

Now, given the `text` string, here is what is going on:

1. Group 1 executes.  It matches the first `">"`.
2. Group 2 executes.  It evaluates the options of its alternation in order.

   1. The first option of group 2's alternation executes.  It matches `"675-441-3144"`.
   2. Group 2's alternation successfully short-circuits upon the match of one of its options.

      - Group 2 as a whole is now equal to the option that matched, which is `"675-441-3144"`.
      - The cursor is now positioned immediately after `"675-441-3144"`, which is immediately before `";;;78888464#"`.
3. Group 11 executes.  It matches everything up through the next `"<"`, which is all of `";;;78888464#<"`.

Thus, some of the content that you want to be in group 2 is actually in group 11 instead.

#### The Solution

Do both of the following two things:

- Convert the contents of group 2 from

  ```
  option1|option2
  ```

  to

  ```
  option1(option2)?|option2
  ```
- Change `$11` in your replacement pattern to `$12`.

This will greedy match one or both options, rather than only one option.  The modification to the replacement pattern is because we have added a group.

### Part 2

#### The Problem

Now that we have modified the regex, our original "option 2" no longer makes sense.  Given our new pattern template `option1(option2)?|option2`, it will be impossible for group 2 to match `"675-441-3144;;;78888464#"`.  This is because our original "option 1" will match all of `"675-441-3144"` and then stop.  Our original "option 2" will then attempt to match `";;;78888464#"`, but will be unable to because it begins with a mandatory capture group of 6-10 digits:  `(\d{6,16})`, but `";;;78888464#"` begins with a semicolon.

#### The Solution

Convert the contents of our original "option 2" from

```
(\d{6,16})([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?
```

to

```
([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?
```

### Part 3

#### The Problem

We have one final problem to solve.  Now that our original "option 2" consists only of a single group with the `?` quantifier, it is possible for it to successfully match a zero-length substring.  So our pattern template `option1(newoption2)?|newoption2` could result in a zero-length match, which does not fulfill the intended purpose of matching phone numbers.

#### The Solution

Do both of the following:

- Convert the contents of our new "option 2" from

  ([;,.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?

  to

  [;,.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?
- Change `$12` in our replacement string to `$10`, since we have now removed one group in two locations.

---

## The Final Solution

Putting everything together, our final solution is as follows.

**Search regex:**

```
(>[^<]*?)((\+?\d{1,4}[ \t\f\-\.](\d[ \t\f\-\.])?)?(\(\d{1,4}([\s-]\d{1,4})?\)[\.\- \t\f])?((\d{2,6}[\.\- \t\f])+\d{2,6})([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?|[;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)([^<]*<)
```

**Replacement regex:**

```
$1<a href="tel:$2">$2</a>$10
```

**Java:**

```
final String searchRegex = "(>[^<]*?)((\\+?\\d{1,4}[ \\t\\f\\-\\.](\\d[ \\t\\f\\-\\.])?)?(\\(\\d{1,4}([\\s-]\\d{1,4})?\\)[\\.\\- \\t\\f])?((\\d{2,6}[\\.\\- \\t\\f])+\\d{2,6})([;,\\.]{1,3}\\d{3,}#?)?|[;,\\.]{1,3}\\d{3,}#?)([^<]*<)";
final String replacementRegex = "$1<a href=\"tel:$2\">$2</a>$10";

String text = "<span style=\"font-size:11.0pt\">675-441-3144;;;78888464#<o:p></o:p></span>";
String replacement = text.replaceAll(searchRegex, replacementRegex);
```

[Proof of correctness](https://regex101.com/r/NPES2f/1)

Comment: Much appreciated, but perhaps the real answer is that this is not a problem that should be solved with regex to begin with. No developer after OP will understand what the heck is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after trying to do it with replaceall without success, I had to implement the replacement method by myself:

```
public static String parsePhoneNumbers(String html){
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder(120);
    regex.append("(>[^<]*?)(")
       .append("((\+?\d{1,4}[ \t\f\-\.](\d[ \t\f\-\.])?)?")
       .append("(\(\d{1,4}([\s-]\d{1,4})?\)[\.\- \t\f])?")
       .append("((\d{2,6}[\.\- \t\f])+\d{2,6})|(\d{6,16})")
       .append("([;,\.]{1,3}\d{3,}#?)?)") 
       .append(")+([^<]*<)");

    StringBuilder mutableHtml = new StringBuilder(html.length());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    int start = 0;

    while(matcher.find()){
        mutableHtml.append(html.substring(start, matcher.start()));
        mutableHtml.append(matcher.group(1)).append("<a href=\"tel:")
                .append(matcher.group(2)).append("\">").append(matcher.group(2))
                .append("</a>").append(matcher.group(matcher.groupCount()));
        start = matcher.end();

    }
    mutableHtml.append(html.substring(start));
    return mutableHtml.toString();
}
```

Comment: Those string literals are not properly escaped.  Regex uses an escape as a metacharacter for control.  However, Java will interpret it as a string escape for special character entry.  So you need to escape the escape for the compiler to not complain about an "Incorrect escape sequence".  E.g. Regex `\d` -> Java `\\d`

Comment: And if this is still the same regex, then it won't work anyway.  See my "Part 1" for the explanation why.